# How can i determine correct transaction order?(Order in which transactions were done in the account)

Tags: yodlee

Yodlee seems to be returning running balance for each transaction returned in the API response but here i am facing an issue where i am not able to determine the correct order of transactions and hence the running balance displayed in my app does'nt make any sense because the transactions are not in correct order i.e. the order in which they happened @ bank.

Is there any solution to this?
I will really appreciate a proper solutions or any work around for this issue

## Note

I have already tried to sort by the id returned for each transaction but it results in incorrect order of transactions

Answer (score 0):

The order can be determined by the transactionDate if returned , Yodlee does not know what order the transactions are nor does it store chronologically. 
Its dependent on the end Site  from where its scraped and most of the banks are missing the transaction Date .